Display full amount value number double in words with vb.net
I'm trying display full amount value number double in words with vb.net
but the double result after the point is not according to
is there anything wrong with my code but for integer values there is no problem
This is actually used for other countries' currencies so it's posted as a guideline so I can adjust it more easily
Please guide me
Thanks
Code in Module
module modvalueinwords
    Public Function ConvertCurrencyToEnglish(ByVal MyNumber As Double) As String
        Dim Temp As String
        Dim Dollars, Cents As String
        Dim DecimalPlace, Count As Integer
        Dim Place(9) As String
        Dim Numb As String
        Place(2) = " Thousand " : Place(3) = " Million " : Place(4) = " Billion " : Place(5) = " Trillion "
        ' Convert Numb to a string, trimming extra spaces.
        Numb = Trim(Str(MyNumber))
        ' Find decimal place.
        DecimalPlace = InStr(Numb, ".")
        ' If we find decimal place...
        If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
            ' Convert cents
            Temp = Left(Mid(Numb, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2)
            Cents = ConvertTens(Temp)
            ' Strip off cents from remainder to convert.
            Numb = Trim(Left(Numb, DecimalPlace - 1))
        End If
        Count = 1
        Do While Numb <> ""
            ' Convert last 3 digits of Numb to English dollars.
            Temp = ConvertHundreds(Right(Numb, 3))
            If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
            If Len(Numb) > 3 Then
                ' Remove last 3 converted digits from Numb.
                Numb = Left(Numb, Len(Numb) - 3)
            Else
                Numb = ""
            End If
            Count = Count + 1
        Loop

        ' Clean up dollars.
        Select Case Dollars
            Case "" : Dollars = "No "
            Case "One" : Dollars = "One"
            Case Else : Dollars = Dollars & ""
        End Select

        ' Clean up cents.
        Select Case Cents
            Case "" : Cents = ""
            Case "One" : Cents = " Point Zero One"
            Case Else : Cents = " Point " & Cents & ""
        End Select
        ConvertCurrencyToEnglish = Dollars & Cents
    End Function

    Private Function ConvertHundreds(ByVal MyNumber As String) As String
        Dim Result As String
        ' Exit if there is nothing to convert.
        If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
        ' Append leading zeros to number.
        MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)
        ' Do we have a hundreds place digit to convert?
        If Left(MyNumber, 1) <> "0" Then
            Result = ConvertDigit(Left(MyNumber, 1)) & " Hundred "
        End If
        ' Do we have a tens place digit to convert?
        If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
            Result = Result & ConvertTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
        Else
            ' If not, then convert the ones place digit.
            Result = Result & ConvertDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
        End If
        ConvertHundreds = Trim(Result)
    End Function

    Private Function ConvertTens(ByVal MyTens As String) As String
        Dim Result As String
        ' Is value between 10 and 19?
        If Val(Left(MyTens, 1)) = 1 Then
            Select Case Val(MyTens)
                Case 10 : Result = "Ten"
                Case 11 : Result = "Eleven"
                Case 12 : Result = "Twelve"
                Case 13 : Result = "Thirteen"
                Case 14 : Result = "Fourteen"
                Case 15 : Result = "Fifteen"
                Case 16 : Result = "Sixteen"
                Case 17 : Result = "Seventeen"
                Case 18 : Result = "Eighteen"
                Case 19 : Result = "Nineteen"
                Case Else
            End Select
        Else
            ' .. otherwise it's between 20 and 99.
            Select Case Val(Left(MyTens, 1))
                Case 2 : Result = "Twenty "
                Case 3 : Result = "Thirty "
                Case 4 : Result = "Forty "
                Case 5 : Result = "Fifty "
                Case 6 : Result = "Sixty "
                Case 7 : Result = "Seventy "
                Case 8 : Result = "Eighty "
                Case 9 : Result = "Ninety "
                Case Else
            End Select
            ' Convert ones place digit.
            Result = Result & ConvertDigit(Right(MyTens, 1))
        End If
        ConvertTens = Result
    End Function

    Private Function ConvertDigit(ByVal MyDigit As String) As String
        Select Case Val(MyDigit)
            Case 1 : ConvertDigit = "One"
            Case 2 : ConvertDigit = "Two"
            Case 3 : ConvertDigit = "Three"
            Case 4 : ConvertDigit = "Four"
            Case 5 : ConvertDigit = "Five"
            Case 6 : ConvertDigit = "Six"
            Case 7 : ConvertDigit = "Seven"
            Case 8 : ConvertDigit = "Eight"
            Case 9 : ConvertDigit = "Nine"
            Case Else : ConvertDigit = ""
        End Select
    End Function
End Module

Code in form
Public Class Form2
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim UserInput As Double
        If Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, UserInput) Then
            TextBox2.Text = ConvertCurrencyToEnglish(CDbl(TextBox1.Text)) + " Dollar"
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

below Result from code and desired result
Value :
10.55

Result code :
Ten Point Fifty Five Dollar

Desired result :
Ten Point Five Five Dollar

Value :
10.5

Result code :
Ten Point Fifty  Dollar

Desired result without extra space :
Ten Point Five Five Dollar

Value :
10.55555

Result code :
Ten Point Fifty Five Dollar


Desired result :
Ten Point Five Five Five Five Five Dollar

Value :
10.5555555555

Result code :
Ten Point Fifty Five Dollar

Desired result
Ten Point Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Dollar


There is no such thing as "Ten Point Five Five Five Dollar". There is no unit of US currency smaller than one cent, which means that the maximum you can have is "Point Nine Nine". Your code seems to know that already, even though you don't.

@KenWhite , thanks for reply . This is actually used for other countries' currencies so it's posted as a guideline so I can adjust it more easily. Please guide me so I can achieve custom Display full amount value number double in words

Either use the debugger to step through the code to see where it's differing from what you want, and change it to behave the way you want it to, or go back and ask the person you copy/pasted it from what needs to be changed to work for you. And if it's returning "Dollars", it's not for many other currencies than the US.

IMO the worst part is the + " Dollar". This makes it so clear that it's used for other countries. Pluralize it when appropriate, break it into dollar / dollars and cent / cents. Also, + is not how strings are concatenated in vb.net, use &
